# DreamFactory remote SQL Service: Failed to launch service “servicename” :CDbConnection failed to open the DB connection

Tags: sql-server

I have installed Bitnami DreamFactory WAMP Stack on windows
server 2008 R2. I am unable to connect to a MS SQL DB through a service
in Dream Factory. The error message I get is “Failed to launch service
“servicename”: CDbConnection failed to open the DB connection”

I have tried everything that is mentioned over here: http://community.dreamfactory.com/t/connecting-to-ms-sql-server/163

Eagerly awaiting help.

Answer (score 0):

Native ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server must be installed for the PHP extensions to connect MS SQL DB.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend referring to [the DreamFactory documentation](https://github.com/dreamfactorysoftware/dsp-core/wiki/SQL-Database-Services#sqlsrv) for all drivers and modules necessary in Windows for SQL Server connections. Depending on your environment, you may need to install more than just the ODBC Driver 11. Bitnami cannot package and distribute the Microsoft drivers.